# Mule HTTP transport deprecated

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I use the new HTTP Connector as mentioned in the online documentation:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081"/>
<flow name="test_flow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="NEW HTTP Connector"/>
    <...>
</flow>
```

Yet, when deploying in DEV on Cloudhub, I still get the message:

> HTTP transport is deprecated and will be removed in Mule 4.0. Use HTTP
>   module instead.

I'm not sure what to look for. Is this a known issue?

Comment: ignore my answer i didnt read the question properly. sorry :)

Comment: You may have another reference to the deprecated HTTP transport somewhere in your app. Can you provide your complete app xml file?

Comment: @PierreB. There are a few xml files in every project, but non contain any reference to the (soon to be) deprecated HTTP transport (`<http:inbound-endpoint />`, same for outbound). I checked this with the filesearch in Anypoint Studio, and double checked with grep in the terminal. I cannot post the XML, because it is company property and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to publish this.

Comment: In the code, this message is defined in [HttpNamespaceHandler](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/ba6f6b965e28eac9a675a096badc9aa64c9892c2/transports/http/src/main/java/org/mule/compatibility/transport/http/config/HttpNamespaceHandler.java). Javadoc says: `for handling <code><http:connector></code> elements`. Did you define any deprecated http element beside inbound-endpoint and outbound-endpoint? Maybe look for "http:*" to check all you http related definitions.

Comment: @PierreB. Thanks for the resource, it's useful. I checked all elements but unfortunately, but to no avail. It's a mystery...

Answer (score 0):

While deploying to mule cloudhub, please change the host in listener config from local host to the default All interfaces [0.0.0.0].

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTTP Connector to use "0.0.0.0" instead of your CloudHub domain name and redeploy.